# Show more fullcalendar data in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have the fullcalendar jQuery plugin working, but I'd like to show more data (registration info, event location, contact info...) in a jQuery dialog when someone clicks on a event. Could someone point me to an example of this? I the future I'll need to make this dialog into a registration form, but 1 step at a time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you miss the [jQuery dialog demo that shows a modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)?

Answer (score 0):

Another nice plugin is [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). Adam even gives a quick example of how to incorporate it into the calendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/